# Vue material dialog - Clear v-model when open dialog

Tags: vuejs2, vue-material

I’ve made a dialog using vu- material, everything works fine but I have a form inside the dialog which I want to clean every time I open the dialog, the problem is if I don’t change page, all my v-model inside the dialog keep the data I have before closing the dialog.
I tried using created / mounted / updated hook to clean my v-model but these hooks don’t get triggered when I don’t change page.

Here's a part of my code :

**Toolbarnav.vue :**

```
<template>
...
<md-dialog md-open-from="#uploadBtn" ref="uploadDialog">
  <md-dialog-title>Upload file</md-dialog-title>
  <md-dialog-content>
    <upload-dialog></upload-dialog>
  </md-dialog-content>
  <md-dialog-actions class="md-align-center">
    <md-button class="md-primary" @click.native="closeUploadDialog()">Fermer</md-button>
  </md-dialog-actions>
</md-dialog>
...
</template>
<script>
...
openUploadDialog() {
    this.$refs.uploadDialog.open();
  },
  closeUploadDialog() {
    this.$refs.uploadDialog.close();
  },
...
</script>
```

**UploadDialog.vue :**

```
<template>
...
<md-input-container>
    <label>Nom</label>
    <md-input id="nom" v-model="nom"></md-input>
</md-input-container> 
<md-input-container>
    <label>Prénom</label>
    <md-input id="prenom" v-model="prenom"></md-input>
</md-input-container> 
<md-input-container>
    <label>Email</label>
    <md-input id="email" v-model="email"></md-input>
</md-input-container> 
...
</template>
<script>
...
name: upload-dialog',
data() {
  return {
    files: [],
    nom: '',
    prenom: '',
    email: '',
  };
},
...
created() {
    this.files = [];
    this.nom = '';
    this.prenom = '';
    this.email = '';
},
</script>
```

Any idea to do this ?
Thanks

Comment: From Vue oficial docs (https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref)
An important note about the ref registration timing: because the refs themselves are created as a result of the render function, you cannot
> access them on the initial render - they don’t exist yet! $refs is
also non-reactive, therefore you should not attempt to use it in
templates for data-binding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use one of the opening/closing events:

- `md-opened`
- `md-closed`

And do the cleaning there, instead of in the `created`/`mounted` lifecycle events.

Example:

```
<md-dialog ... @md-opened="myOpenMethod" @md-closed="myCloseMethod">
```

```js
new Vue({
  ...
  methods: {
    myOpenMethod() { console.log('opened'); },
    myCloseMethod() { console.log('closed'); }
  },
  ...
})
```

See [**demo CodePen** here](https://codepen.io/acdcjunior/pen/VQqEjj).

## Forcing recreation of the dialog component

If you can only change `Toolbarnav.vue`, you can use `:key` to force the recreation of the `<upload-dialog>`. Steps below.

First create a `uploadDialogKey: 1` in `data`:

```
data() {
  return {
    ...
    uploadDialogKey: 1
  }
},
```

Add `key` to the declaration of the dialog:

```
<upload-dialog :key="uploadDialogKey"></upload-dialog>
```

Now everytime you change the `uploadDialogKey` property, Vue will recreate the component.

Since you want to recreate the dialog on `openUploadDialog()`, change it to:

```
openUploadDialog() {
  this.uploadDialogKey++;              // <=== added this line
  this.$refs.uploadDialog.open();
},
```

[**Demo CodePen** of this solution here](https://codepen.io/acdcjunior/pen/VQgWdx).

Comment: Thanks acdcjunior !
But my md-dialog declaration is inside Toolbarnav.vue so I can't update the UploadFileDialog.vue data

Comment: Inside ToolbarNav.vue I can't update nothing (I think) in UploadFileDialog.vue, that's why I tried differents hooks to make the update inside UploadFileDialog.vue but that's works only if I change page